# why is multiplying a sum in a recursion different from multiplying the individual integers then summing?

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I am solving the following problem: we are given a nested list of integers, and we want to find the product sum. The product sum is simply the sum of the numbers, however for numbers in a nested list, we need to multiply them with the depth of the nesting.

For example: array = [2,5,[7,-1]]  -> output = 19 ### 2+5+ 2*(7+ -1)

Here is a correct recursive solution:

```
def productSum(array, multiplier = 1):
    total_sum = 0 
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        if isinstance(array[i],int): 
            total_sum += array[i]
        else: 
            total_sum += productSum(array[i],multiplier+1)
    
    return total_sum *multiplier
```

However, when I initially wrote my solution, rather than having the *multiplier at the end with the return, I had the multiplier within the 'if' statement, so my solution was:

```
def productSum(array, multiplier = 1):
    total_sum = 0 
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        if isinstance(array[i],int): 
            total_sum += array[i] * multiplier
        else: 
            total_sum += productSum(array[i],multiplier+1)

    return total_sum
```

I just want to understand why my solution above doesn't produce the desired result, because my understanding is that they are the same, since within each recursion call the 'multiplier' is fixed, so why does it matter if I multiply the integers with the multiplier then sum them, vs. summing the integers then multiplying with the multiplier??? Which, if I understand the above correctly is the difference between the two.

To give an example, with the input: array: [5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]], the first solution produces 27, which is correct, however the second solution produces 12, which is wrong!

Comment: The first case multiplies *all elements* of them sum, the second code only multiplies  *integer/leaf elements* of the sum. Note that your task description doesn't make it clear which behaviour is desired.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, thought I was reading it wrongly. Thanks Mister, I this as well now.

Comment: for `[5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]]` isn't 12 the correct answer ? `5 + 2 + 2*(7 + -1) + 3 + 2*(6 + 3*(-13 + 8) + 4) = 12`

Comment: @AlainT. it is, i think he's mistaken with 27 and 12. 1st solution gives 12 which is right and 2nd solution gives 27 which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, in the initial solution, you were not multiplying `productSum(array[i],multiplier+1)` by the multiplier.

If you want to only multiply the numeric values, your multiplier needs to be the factorial of the depth level because the multiplications compound over each other.

for example:

```
[5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]]
```

computes as:

```
5 + 2 + 2*(7 + -1) + 3 + 2*(6 + 3*(-13 + 8) + 4)
```

propagating the multiplications:

```
5 + 2 + 2*7 + 2*-1 + 3 + 2*6 + 2*3*-13 + 2*3*8 + 2*4
```

Note that -13 and 8 are multiplied by 2 AND 3 (not just by 3 as your initial code would do).

BTW, you could use the sum function over a comprehension instead of a for-loop.

```
# like 'correct' solution:        depth * ∑ recursion | value
def productSum(a,d=1):
    return d*sum(productSum(n,d+1) if isinstance(n,list) else n for n in a)

# like initial solution (fixed):  ∑ depth * (recursion | value)
def productSum(a,d=1):
    return sum(productSum(n,d+1)*d for n in a) if isinstance(a,list) else a 

# or factorial approach:          ∑ (recursion | value * depth!)
def productSum(a,d=1,m=1):
    return sum(productSum(n,d+1,m*d) for n in a) if isinstance(a,list) else a*m
```